# Flask server is having formparser error when accepting FormData, but only occasionally

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I'm trying to pass a file from a react application to a flask server. The file is populated from an upload form, and pressing a button triggers a fetch call. Based on console logging, I believe the file is being passed successfully to the function. I know it's weird that I'm not using the file object being passed in, but I'm assigning the file value to this member variable elsewhere in the code. Here is the react code:

```
onDrop = (file) => {
    var test = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"

    const fileData = new FormData();
    fileData.append('file', this.imageFile.files[0]);

    fetch(test, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: fileData ,
        mode: 'no-cors',
    })
    .then(success => {
            console.log("worked");
        })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("failed!");
    });
};
```

I have a flask server running on port 5000. It is accepting the request, but there is a parsing error going on that I cannot understand. Here is the flask server code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_function():

        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
            # 'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
        }

        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return '', 200, headers
        huh = request

        return 'Hello World!'
```

I have setup breakpoints in this code, and am seeing a weird stacktrace about parsing errors. the most maddening thing is that this does NOT happen about 10% of the time, and the file makes it to flask successfully.

[The request object at a debug point inside of the flask endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrrjx.png)

Comment: Can we please see the full Traceback with the error message so we know the context of the problem?

Comment: I am struggling to figure out how to see the full traceback. When I right click and copy value, I get this:400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: Run your flask app file with debug set to true. The flask docs explain how to do this

Comment: Also be sure to declare the appropriate content type for the request

Comment: I have debug mode enabled, is there anything special I should be seeing?

            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
Still didnt work :(